# Ruby on Windows XP: How to change directory of SSL certificates

Tags: ruby, ssl, directory, certificate

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows XP, and run this script:

```
# testSSL.rb
require 'open-uri'
open('https://www.google.com')
```

I get a "certificate verify failed" error on http.rb line 921.
Testing further, it seems that Ruby looks for the SSL certificates files here:

```
C:/Users/Justin/Projects/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.1l/ssl
```

How can I tell Ruby to look for these files where they were installed:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ssl_certs.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, but you get a warning because you overwrite a constant

```
OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE = 'C:/Users/Gebruiker/cert.pem'
puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
```

or like this

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']="C:/users/username/cert.pem" #make sure a correct certificate is there
```

In both cases followed by

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

You can download a valid .pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. Save this file to with the extension .pem in the path and with the name you reference in your script.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, but this didn't work (tried it with eight PEM files). The X509 object always returns the same  "certificate verify failed" error, including when I specify a non-existing file or path.

Comment: that's just the point, you have to make sure the file exists and is valid (there are different type's of .pem certificates), there is a solution without a .pem file but I don't publish it because it produces hate comments because it is unsafe